# A $20$-degenerate graph on $1000$ vertices has to have at least $501$ vertices whose degree is at most $80$.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm seriously at a loss here...
I'm asked to prove or disprove the following statement:
A $20$-degenerate graph on $1000$ vertices has to have at least $501$ vertices whose degree is at most $80$.
I'd shown you what I have tried so far, but it isn't even close to a solution.
I really don't know how to approach this one..
any leads?..

Comment: No, but in what way exactly, I mean how would it being a 20 degenerated graph play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graph is 20-degenerate, then the number of edges is less than 20 times the number of vertices, right? So the degree-sum is less than 40 times the number of vertices? So the average degree is less than 40? Well, if half the vertices had degree more than 80, wouldn't that make the average degree more than 40?

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it, you sir are a savior :]